# Is it safe to use "==" for comparison with null?

Tags: scala

I had used expression `obj != null` for countless times. Sometimes I use `null == obj`.

I had read piece of scala standard library sources recently and discovered that `obj eq null` is the only form for comparison used there.

Is it safe to use operator ( that is sugar to `.equals`) version for `null` comparison? May some implicit magic crush normal comparison logic with `==` version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `==` for object comparison, and nulls will safely use `eq` over `equals` when necessary.

See the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.Any@==(x$1:Any):Boolean) for `==`:

> Test two objects for equality. The expression`x == that` is equivalent to `if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that)`.

So if you have `val s: String = null`, and you check that `s == null`, then `s eq null` is true, so the `if` is true, and it returns `null eq null`, which is also true.

In fact, using `==` is always safer than using `equals`, because you might actually call `s.equals(s)` (where `s` is `null`), which would throw a NPE.

Comment: But it still may be redefined.

Comment: @ayvango `==` is `final`, so no, it can't.

Comment: final is good. It allows to optimize out redundant comparison, if write `null` at left position: `null.==(obj)`

Comment: Actually, the compiler will also optimize if the `null` is on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is,
I add:
If you to speed up your program, use

```
null == ptr
```

The program will compile faster

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

In scala, `==` is to be preferred over `equals` as it handles `null` and is aware of numerical equivalence (`1==1L` but `!1.equals(1L)`)

If you want reference equality, use eq.

Comment: But scala library does not use `==`. It use `eq`

Comment: ``eq`` is for reference equality.

Comment: I know. Is there any reason I should prefer `eq` for null comparison?

Answer (score -1):

The issue I have whith using == to test against null is illustrated by the code below:

```
class X {
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = true
}
var x: X = null
println(new X == x) // true and treacherous /!\ 
println(new X == null) // false
println(new X equals x) // true
println(new X equals null) // true
println(new X eq x) // false and sound /!\ 
println(new X eq null) // false
```

So if you text explicitely against null as in *new X == null* you're good but if you test against an object stored in a varible and being potentially null, then beware of *==* if *equals* was overriden. That's not en issue with *eq*, so I default to *eq*. I only use *==* when I want to use equals, for instance with Strings, never with null.